# PRi.GPIO works as normal user but for root ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, python-3

I am not a Linux specialist and would be glad if you could help me with this problem.

Environment:
Raspi 3b with Debian
uname -a gives the following output:
Linux MM3 6.1.21-v7+ #1642 SMP Mon Apr 3 17:20:52 BST 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux

If I start python3 as normal user "pi" and call "import RPi.GPIO as GPIO", then it works. Not as root (see screenshot below).
Unfortunately, I cannot start such a Python script for a PIR as a service.
What is the user root missing that the user "pi" has?
Many thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your `su - root`... that doesn't work on my Pi. And **why** do you want to run Python as `root`?

Comment: **DO NOT** post pictures of text post text

Comment: What OS? You tag "raspbian" but DO NOT appear to be using *Raspberry Pi OS* - the included python is 3.9.2 or have done some undisclosed action.

Comment: I want the Python script here:
/lib/systemd/system
as a service when starting the Raspi:
pir_sensor.service
This is not done with the user "pi" but as "root" or "system", right?
Contents of pir_sensor.service:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I want the python script here:
/lib/systemd/system
as a service when starting the raspi:
pir_sensor.service
This is not done with the user "pi" but as "root" or "system", right?
Something like described here: [Link to github.com](https://github.com/acejacek/pir_hdmi)

Contents of pir_sensor.service:

---

```
[Unit]
Description=MagicMirror PIR Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/MagicMirror
Restart=on-failure
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/pi/MagicMirror/pirx.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

And the start of my pirx.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf8 #
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

Sorry for posting a picture.
OS is Bullseye on a raspberry pi 3b
As you can see it is updated to 3.9.7 but it seems that something went wrong.
That the reason i ask to repair python.
Thanks for your help